# REST WCF Service from URI - ArrayOf - Null Elements

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, rest

When I call the my service as below the XML elements TruckName and Website are null? Clearly the elements are poupulated in the XML on the web page (see xml below). I believe its related to the ArrayOf element being first? Below is also the code from my console app calling the method GetInfo(). Do I need to get rid of the ArrayOfFoodTruck element? If so whats the easiest way. thanks to all in advance..

```
- <ArrayOfFoodTruck xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WCFServiceLibrary" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
- <FoodTruck>
 <Company i:nil="true" /> 
 <DayOfWeek i:nil="true" /> 
 <Location i:nil="true" /> 
 <TimeOfDay i:nil="true" /> 
 <TruckID>0</TruckID> 
 <TruckName>Truck 87</TruckName> 
 <Website>http://www.test.com</Website> 
 </FoodTruck>
- <FoodTruck>
<Company i:nil="true" /> 
<DayOfWeek i:nil="true" /> 
<Location i:nil="true" /> 
<TimeOfDay i:nil="true" /> 
<TruckID>0</TruckID> 
<TruckName>Bon Me</TruckName> 
<Website>http://www.test.com</Website> 
</FoodTruck>
</ArrayOfFoodTruck>
```

This is the call from my console app..

```
    static void GetInfo()
    {

        XElement rootXml = XElement.Load("http://localhost:5150/getnames");

         var FoodTruck = from C in rootXml.Elements()
         select new { TruckName = (string)C.Element("TruckName"), WebSite = (string)C.Element("Website") };
         foreach (var x in FoodTruck)

         Console.WriteLine("{0}\r\n{1}", x.TruckName, x.WebSite);
         Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have problem with the namespace

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(.....);
XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WCFServiceLibrary");

var result = xDoc.Descendants(ns+"FoodTruck")
    .Select(n => new 
    { 
        TruckName=n.Element(ns+"TruckName").Value,
        WebSite = n.Element(ns+"Website").Value
    })
    .ToArray();
```

**--EDIT--**  **OR**

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FoodTruck[]), "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WCFServiceLibrary");
var foodTrucks = (FoodTruck[])ser.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));

public class FoodTruck
{
    public string Website;
    public string TruckName;
}
```

Comment: Yes that works thank you L.B... Also is the above way a good practice to use when using C# to return the results from a REST service? Or is there a better more efficient way..

Comment: @midnightCoder If you are not doing the same thing tausends of times per second, "efficiency" should not be a problem. Deserializing to a concrete class can be another alternative.